# How to make a UI for sentence divider?

Tags: language-agnostic

Currently I am working on a web system which can divide an article into sentences automatically. When using this system, a user just uploads plain texts and waits for the system to divide it. If the system makes something wrong, the user can add or delete "divides" to correct it.

[image]

This is what the system might look like, where red columns stand for "divides". I want to achieve that: if a user clicks on a column, it disappears; if a user clicks on "nothing", a column appears. Later, this modified result is submitted to the system.

By the way, I am considering using `int[]` as positions of columns. If this is a bad choice, please kindly correct me.

Is there any existing solution for this? If not, how should I make it? I am sorry, but I am in complete darkness right now and not able to provider further details.

EDIT:

What I am asking is: is there any existing dev tools for sentence dividing (or article manipulating)? To show and edit the "divides" and later store them.

Comment: I don't see what you've tried, nor do you mention what language(s) you're using.

Comment: @j08691 I only need the modification part, and I guess javascript is in need.

Comment: Only gaps between words?

Comment: @Alex K. Currently, yes. But this system may not limited to English in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace potential insertion points (whitespace) with a placeholder element to provide you with something clickable, do the same for the existing delimiters.

Rough; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/a3U8v/